# Jenkins Email-ext plugin is no longer visible in the project's post build options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

Does any one have any idea what could have happened to Jenkins Email-ext? We have had this plugin working just fine for over two years and all of sudden our entire configs for this plugin have disappeared from all of our projects. We tried to uninstall and re-install the plugin but that didn't make any difference.

Once you install this plugin there should be a checkbox under "Post-build Actions" section in the projects config page to enable it but this option is not shown any longer here. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed by following the below steps:

1. Uninstall email-ext plugin from Jenkins
2. Stop Jenkins services. (Run > Services.msc) find Jenkins and stop it
3. Go to Jenkins home (base folder) > Plugins and remove any instances of email-ext plugin (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins)
4. Restart Jenkins
5. Install email-ext plugin again

And now everything should be working OK again!

Answer (score 0):

if you haven't upgraded your jenkins then the issue might be a different one , just to make sure email configuration section has completely removed from your job , check the config.xml of your jenkins job for the keyword [email-ext].

how to check job's config.xml from GUI ?

simple click on configure link of your job you will be redirected to something like  below

**http://yourserver/job/jobname/configure**

now change the last part of url [configure to config.xml] resulting in something like  below

**http://yourserver/job/jobname/config.xml**

now search for keywords like email and email-ext , if you did not find anything then email-ext plugin is not functioning or its has completely removed the email configuration from your job , if you find an entry , do a uninstall /install and then try a restart of jenkins might resolve your problem , or else you can try the option of reloading configuration from disk.

Comment: Thank you @prudviraj! but this did not help. there is no email or email-ext keywords on config.xml. On Plugin page we have the latest Email Extension Plugin (2.42) but for some reason we can't activate this plugin to use it! We also have the latest Jenkins upgrade in place. Jenkins (2.2)